# About Gibbs energy

Tags: thermodynamics

In the Gibbs energy equation change in entropy is multiplied to temperature. But since entropy itself is energy exchange÷temperature. Then isn't entropy*temperature is equal to energy exchange. And Gibbs energy not dependent on temperature. Please explain I am confused!

But I already know that Gibbs energy change is dependent on temperature, by which I mean Entropy = energy exchange ÷ temperature. Why this contradiction?

Comment: Entropy itself is neither "energy exchange" nor "temperature", it is a measure for the available microstates to a thermodynamic system. I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @ACuriousMind You are missing the division sign between the "energy exchange" and "temperature.

Comment: @Steeven: I see (that looks like an equal sign if one squints, and I don't usually ever see that division sign). Still don't get the question, though, as entropy is the *integral* of that ratio.